# Find matches to regex '[^,] which' in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I wish to Find instances of the substring `[^,] which` — the word `which` preceded by a space '' that is preceded by a character that is not a comma `[^,]`. Can this be done?

The query `[,] which` works fine but the negation breaks the regex. Is there a special syntax in MS Word or is this not available within the Find/Replace dialogue?

When I try this query I get the Warning dialogue, `^ is not a valid special character for the Find What box or is not supported when the Use Wildcards check box is selected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[!,]`; from [this article](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx):

> t[!a-m]ck finds "tock" and "tuck," but not "tack" or "tick."